# How to load data from an excel sheet and make populate options for a survey?

Tags: google-forms

I wanted to create a tool to collect follow-up data from people. I have a dataset with over 10,000 entries, each collected by one of 200 data collectors. There are over 10,000 individuals in total. In the tool, I need a drop down to select a data collector's names. Then, based on that selection, display the individuals they interviewed in another dropdown. Finally, after selecting an individual, show the data they provided in subsequent dropdowns. I have tried this with google sheets.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question to the point that I wonder whether there _IS_ a question. You tagged `Google Forms`: this is a tool for data collection, not data analysis. You said `I have tried this with google sheets.` but you didn't explain _what_ you have tried. In any event the key issues are: what is the format of the your dataset (handwritten, digital; the title mentions Excel) and what does it look like. The analysis that you outline is do-able. If you want further assistance, please provide a sample of your data as well as an example of the outputs that you want.